# Need confirmation on BoneCP

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am starting to you bone cp. 
So far below is what I have done my centos 6 
Below is how I have put my files on my centos 6.

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/guava-11.0.2.jar
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/slf4j-1.6.4 (the whole folder I just put here).
```

Below is the error I got now.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig.<clinit>(BoneCPConfig.java:60)
        at commServer.<init>(cServer.java:6594)
        at commServer.main(cServer.java:6579)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Comment: add your error message is... ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't have the `SLF4J` library associated with your project. `BoneCP` needs 2 extra libraries and `SLF4J` is one of them. You can find the required libraries [here.](http://jolbox.com/index.html?page=http://jolbox.com/requirements.html)

Comment: I have visited the page and from the requirement page I have put this both can you see /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/guava-11.0.2.jar
(Google Guava) and /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/slf4j-1.6.4( logging tool). What else could be wrong?

Comment: I have added this two files now directly into the folder./usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar and /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar? It can compile now? So will the logs works now properly.